# Using Eve and Flask in one application

Tags: python, flask, eve

I want to provide REST interface and a single page JS-application for consuming the REST-service. Is there a way to do both in one python app or should I start eve-app for providing REST and flask-app for providing HTML as two processes?

Answer (score 5):

[The `Eve` instance *is* a Flask app.](http://python-eve.org/features.html#powered-by-flask) It's a subclass of `Flask` adding Eve-specific behavior. Use that instance as you would a `Flask` instance.

```
app = Eve()

@app.route(...)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If your flask app is only for serving static files, you don't even need a flask app. You may be able to directly serve static assets via Nginx